# Width transition tailwind CSS

Tags: css-transitions, width, tailwind-css, hidden

I would like to show and slide an element from the left to the right of the page. To do so, I hide it by default. When a button is clicked, the ul element is displayed and its width goes from 0px to 100vw. I also added a transition on the width property of the ul element.

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <button id="click_me" class="inline-block border-2 p-6"> Click Me! </button>
  <ul id="hidden_nav" class="hidden w-0 h-screen bg-red-50 mt-10 transition-[width] duration-1000">
    <li> Item </li>
    <li> Item </li>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
const btn = document.getElementById('click_me');
const navul = document.getElementById('hidden_nav');
btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
  navul.classList.toggle('hidden');
  navul.classList.toggle('w-0');
  navul.classList.toggle('w-screen');
});
```

Codepen link:

https://codepen.io/Okumak/pen/qBVjwdY

Yet, I cannot see any transition going on and I don't get why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will never work with a `hidden` class. An alternative solution would be `opacity`.

```js
const btn = document.getElementById('click_me');
const navul = document.getElementById('hidden_nav');
btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
  navul.classList.toggle('opacity-0');
  navul.classList.toggle('w-0');
  navul.classList.toggle('w-screen');
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <button id="click_me" class="inline-block border-2 p-6"> Click Me! </button>
  <ul id="hidden_nav" class="opacity-0 w-0 h-screen bg-red-50 mt-10 transition-[width] duration-1000">
    <li> Item </li>
    <li> Item </li>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Just look after the `height`. It still takes up space when hidden, just in case you want to toggle it as well then you can do so.

Comment: Thank you I didn't know that :)! It works perfectly now.

Answer (score 0):

you can add width transition in tailwindcss by creating a custom style for the width transition that will be something like this. It will work for the before element as well as it worked for me. after adding the custom styles you can just add this class to the element you want to add transition to

```
 @layer base {
   html {
   scroll-behavior: smooth;
   font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
 }

     .transition-width {
      transition: width 2s linear;
   }

   .width-transition::before {
     transition: width 2s linear;
    }
  }
```

you can add class for the transition like this. This is animating the psuedo before element.

```
      <div
      ref={textRef}
      className="width-transition relative ml-[400px] text-[80px] 
      duration-1000 before:absolute before:left-0 before:top-0 before:w- 
      [0px] before:overflow-hidden before:text-green-400 before:content- 
     ['TEXT'] hover:before:w-full"
     >
      TEXT
    </div>
```